# How to get other pages titles with same sys_category of the current page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use TYPO3 8.7, I want to display on the current page footer the title of other pages with the same `sys_category` of the current page. When the user reach the bottom of the page he will find "related pages", those pages have the same `sys_category` uid of the current page. Can this be done with typoscript ?

I have tried this code but this didn't work:

```
temp.relatedCAT = CONTENT
temp.relatedCAT {
  table = pages
  select {
    // dontCheckPid doesn't exist for CONTENT objects, so make it recursive from root page (or pidInList.data = leveluid:-2
    pidInList = {$pidRoot}
    recursive = 99
    selectFields = sys_category.uid as catUid
    join = sys_category_record_mm ON pages.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
    where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'pages' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = {TSFE:id}
    where.insertData = 1
    // not necessary for this use case
    // orderBy = sys_category.sorting
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = catUid
    // Hack: if there are no cats selected for a page, all news are displayed
    // so I just pass a catUid that's quite unlikely
    wrap = |
  }
}
lib.related >
lib.related= TEXT
lib.related {

                table = pages
                select {
                        # pid de la racine du site
                        pidInList = 1
                        # récursivité jusqu'au maximum de niveau
                        recursive = 99
                        # jointure sur la sys_cat_mm
                        leftjoin = sys_category_record_mm ON (pages.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign)
                        # condition de recherche
                        where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames =  "pages" AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = {$temp.relatedCAT}
                        where.insertData = 1

}
}
```

Comment: `lib.related= TEXT` does not match the following properties. Should it be `lib.related= CONTENT`?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a HMENU object with `special = categories`?
See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-categories